# NewsModel cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

**/hybris/platform/cuppy/interceptors/NewsSendInterceptor.java 
**>     **final NewsModel news = (NewsModel) model; NewsModel cannot be

> resolved to a type******

Answer (score 1):

The "could not resolve to a type" issue is pretty common.  Try to refresh and clean/build your project in your IDE after you executed *ant clean all*.

The ant script generates the model clases from the *-items.xml file. In some cases the IDE does not recognize these newly generated files.

Answer (score 0):

I am not understanding what exactly you are trying. Assuming that you have created a new **News Model** in *-items.xml file and now you are trying to create a new instance of that.

You can try this ..

```
/** The model service. */
@Autowired
private ModelService modelService;

final NewsModel news = modelService.create(NewsModel.class);
```